# Old Connection increasing TempDB size

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a java application in which it connected to MSSQL database query using a Java Thread every 1 sec for some information, below is pseudo

```
    Get New connection
     Query the DB
if get information looking for
              processes it 
    else 
            it get sleep for 1 sec 
    Clean resources/connect resources free
```

So what happening is, SQL Server allotted SPID 60 to that query initially and when java cleaned up and closed the connection and after 1 sec again asked for a connect to execute same query SQL Server allotted back SPID 60

due to this TempDB file never get free and keep increasing. So my question is: how to ensure that each time I get a new session in sql server? so that tempDB is not keep increasing and holding space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with Connection pool settings and one java code which was keep pooling in 1 sec because of that connection was never closed. below are my settings for JBOSS 5 and mSSQL Server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <datasources>
 <local-tx-datasource>
  <jndi-name>Base_nucleusdv</jndi-name> 
  <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class> 
  <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://db;databaseName=ReportServices;</connection-url>
  <security-domain>EncryptPassword</security-domain>
    <!--pooling parameters-->
    <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <query-timeout>60</query-timeout>
    <track-statements>true</track-statements>
  </local-tx-datasource>
  </datasources>
```